# Add text input dynamically to list with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list (style taken from bootstrap) of elements, to which I want to add some more elements using text input. Here is my code-

```
<div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id = "input" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id = "add" >Add</button>
      </span>

    </div><!-- /input-group -->
<form>
    <ul class="list-group" id = "tagList">

  <li class="list-group-item"> <b>Tags </b></li>  
  <li class="list-group-item"> <span class ="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio">
    </span>Apple</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> <span class ="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio">
    </span> Orange</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> <span class ="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio">
    </span> Pear</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> <span class ="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio">
    </span> Banana</li>
</ul>
</form>


<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script>

$('#add').click(function(){
    var text = $('#input').val();
    if(text.length){
        $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.tagList')
    }
});

 </script>
```

I can get the code to work with a simpler list, but not with this one. Can anyone spot why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following code..

```
    $('#add').click(function(){
    var text = $('#input').val();
    if(text.length){        
    $('ul').append('<li class="list-group-item"><span class ="input-group-addon"> <input type="radio">    </span>'+text+'</li>');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jX2K3/17/)

Comment: That works well in that it adds a new menu item with a radio button, but it ignores the css thats applied to the other menu items, and also produces a duplicate of the new item and puts it on top of the menu bar?! Odd..

Comment: you need to wrap around in span and give class name...
       $('ul').append('<li class="list-group-item"> <span class ="input-group-addon"> <input type="radio">    </span>'+text+'</li>');

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand what you mean by that?

Comment: Thanks but that made an appearance just underneath the menubar with the radio button above it..

Comment: I edited your updated code and removed the ">" after "list-group-item", and that has put the radio button back where it should be. However, its still making a copy of the entry and putting it in the menu bar!!

Comment: that's probably because you have another UL in body and the code above will insert into matching "ul" within body..you need to specify where you want to insert i.e. "tagList"

Comment: Genius, that worked!! I had another ul in the menubar. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your li's are not closed:

```
 <li class="list-group-item" <span class ="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio">
    </span>Apple</li>
```

Should be:

```
 <li class="list-group-item"><span class ="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio">
    </span>Apple</li>
```

Always funny to spot such issues once you placed the code into the code highlighting here on SO.

In order for your javascript to work, you might use the following: http://jsfiddle.net/jX2K3/21/

Comment: Thanks, that's why copy and paste isn't always the best idea!! However, input is still not being added to list?

Comment: Hmm, also the reason the li's aren't closed is to allow for the radio buttons!

Comment: Even if it would work without closing the beginning LI tag, question remains to what extent your page will be parsed on all (modern) browsers.

Comment: See the fiddle for a modified version of @CodeBox which uses clone and works.